# how to get 14.04 auto update to use 4.4.0 kernels

Tags: upgrade

I recently managed to upgrade my 14.04 release to use 4.4.0 kernel, but latest auto-update is for the 3.19.0 kernel.  How do i get auto-update to provide 4.4.0 updates??

update popup does give me checkboxes for both 4.4 and 3.19 kernels.  I tried unchecking 3.19 items, but update still seemed to download 3.19 stuff and 4.4.  It did choose to boot the new 4.4.0, so that is a good thing.